# R plot with an x time axis: how to force the ticks labels to be the days?

Tags: r, plot

I have this file in csv format:

```
timestamp,pages
2011-12-09T11:20:50.33,4
2012-01-23T17:44:02.71,132
2012-01-28T15:07:59.34,168
```

The first column is a timestamp, the second one is a page count.
I need to plot the page count on the vertical axis and the timestamp on the horizontal axis.

The timestamps are not regularly spaced, I have one day in december ant two close days in january.

I tried this code

```
df = read.csv("my_data.csv")
df$timestamp = strptime(df$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
plot(df$timestamp,df$pages)
```

and I got a plot with just one tick on the middle of the x axis and with the label "Jan": it's not wrong but I would like to have three ticks with just the day number and the month.

I tried

```
plot(df$timestamp,df$pages,xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1,df$timestamp,"days")
```

but no x axis is plotted.
Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would `as.Date()` your `timestamp` like this:

```
df$timestamp = as.Date(strptime(df$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
```

This works then:

```
plot(df$timestamp,df$pages,xaxt="n")
axis.Date(1,at=df$timestamp,labels=format(df$timestamp,"%b-%d"),las=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This will work:

```
plot(df$timestamp,df$pages,xaxt="n")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=df$timestamp, labels=format(df$timestamp, "%m/%d"))
```

Essentially in `axis.POSIXct` (note that you have `POSIXct` dates in your data frame) you specify where to have the axis ticks (`at`) and what the labels are.

Typically I like my dates label vertical rather than horizontal. To get that use `par(las=2)` before the plot.

Answer (score 6):

I found this: http://personality-project.org/r/r.plottingdates.html

Which gave me my solution...

```
dm = read.csv("my_data.csv", sep=",", head=TRUE)
dm$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(dm$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
daterange=c(as.POSIXlt(min(dm$DateTime)), as.POSIXlt(max(dm$DateTime)))
plot(pages ~ DateTime, dm, xaxt = "n")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="day"), format="%b %d")
```

The important parts being `daterange` and `at=seq(..., by="day")`.

Comment: Thank you, I had to change your code snippet in order to get a proper result: `dm = read.csv("my_data.csv",sep=",",head=TRUE)
dm$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(dm$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
daterange=c(as.POSIXlt(min(dm$DateTime)), as.POSIXlt(max(dm$DateTime)))
plot(pages ~ DateTime, dm, xaxt = "n")
axis.POSIXct(1, at=seq(daterange[1], daterange[2], by="day"), format="%b %d")`

Comment: @uvts_cvs Aah yep, my date/time were in separate columns. Will update.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this can help. I made this function that allows adding a fixed number of equidistant time ticks.
By setting `first="month"`, the function puts the tick to the 1st of each month. If `first="day"` the function puts the tick to the 00:00 hour of each day.
Of course, the plot must be created with `xaxt="n"` argument.
By default, it adds 10 ticks (`ticks.n=10`) with a dd/mm format (`format.x="%d/%m"`), no first day of the month or day, and horizontal orientation of the labels (`las=1`).

```
axis.time=function(time.x=Sys.time(),ticks.n=10,format.x="%d/%m",first="none",las=1){
  tz=attr(time.x,"tzone")
  if (first == "day"){
    time.x=seq(time.x[1],time.x[length(time.x)],60*30)
    time.x=time.x[which(diff(as.numeric(format(time.x,"%H")))<0)+1]
    time.x=strptime(as.character(as.Date(time.x)),"%Y-%m-%d",tz)
  } else if (first == "month") {
    time.x=seq(time.x[1],time.x[length(time.x)], 60*60*24/2)
    time.x=time.x[which(diff(as.numeric(format(time.x,"%d")))<0)+1]
    time.x=strptime(as.character(as.Date(time.x)),"%Y-%m-%d",tz)
  } else {
    time.x = seq(time.x[1],time.x[length(time.x)], length.out=ticks.n)  
  }
  axis.POSIXct(side = 1,x = time.x,at = time.x,format = format.x,las=las)
```

Suppose you have a data frame:

`df1=data.frame(time=seq(Sys.time()-1e8,Sys.time(),length.out = 100),Y=runif(100))`

a plot with `plot(df1)` will put the X-axis ticks only at the beginning of each year. If you plot as `plot(df1,xaxt="n")` you can use the `axis.time` function:

`axis.time(time.x = df1$time,first = "month",las=2,format.x = "%m-%y")`

to get a tick on the first day of each month and with a different format and alignment.

[image]

Comment: Hello, may you provide an example of use of your function?

Comment: Hello, may you provide an example of use of your function? Starting from `df<-data.frame(
timestamp=c('2011-12-09T11:20:50.33',
'2012-01-23T17:44:02.71',
'2012-01-28T15:07:59.34'),
pages=c(4,132,168)
)`

Comment: I have added an example above.
In your case, I would set the number of ticks without a first day of month:

`axis.time(time.x = df$timestamp,ticks.n = 10,format.x = "%d-%m")`

Comment: Thank you. I would change your `43200` to something less cryptic :-) maybe `60*60*24/2`?